# Stuck on an Axios Get Request

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm trying to send multiple parameters through Axios to an Express Router - however I'm running into an issue, seems I've made a mistake in my code and the parameters I'm passing are coming back as undefined, I'm positive my syntax is incorrect, but I'm running into a brick wall trying to find the solution.

```
export async function getBranchDates(branch, start, end) {
  try {
    console.log("api/index", branch, start, end);
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/dates", {
      branch,
      start,
      end,
    });
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

```
const apiRouter = require("express");
const branchDateRouter = apiRouter.Router();
const { getReportsByBranchDate } = require("../db");

branchDateRouter.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { branch, start, end } = req.body;
    console.log("running dates", req.body);
    // const branch = req.params.id;
    // const start = req.params.start;
    // const end = req.params.end;
    console.log("dates", branch, start, end);
    const branches = await getReportsByBranchDate(branch, start, end);
    // console.log(branches);
    // res.send({
    //   message: "Users is under construction!",
    // });
    res.send({ branches });
  } catch ({ name, message }) {
    next({ name, message });
  }
});

module.exports = branchDateRouter;
```

Comment: Did you test your API with Postman or similar program?

Comment: Not as of yet as my request isn't getting past the express router, on my console.log it's showing undefined as a result of the req.body log.

Comment: Then you should edit you question focusing more on the back-end. Like what did you try, what is the result, etc. You can remove the front-end React as it's not related for now.

Comment: Is the returned data from your server json? If it is, use res.json(branches) instead. Might also need to set the content-type to application/json in the header

Comment: The issue is that the information I'm sending over from axios isn't getting to the express server, everytime I either get undefined or a blank object under my branchDateRouter.

Comment: How did you mount `branchDateRouter`? Do you mount it like `app.use('/api/dates', branchDateRouter)`?

Comment: Where are you using the `body-parser` ? Without `body-parser` middleware, `req.body` will return `undefined`.